# How to make middle Element in ConstraintLayout Chain RTL extend to parent when first part is set to GONE?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Using ConstraintLayout 1.0.2

Let's say we have elements
A B C

In RTL it becomes
C B A

If C visibility is set to GONE it becomes
A B

B has match_constraint width

while A has a fixed width of only 48dp

So B's width will expand to the parent.

It works normally in LTR but when it comes to RTL.

C B A

C is GONE

B is also GONE

A is still present.

_ _ A

**Normal**

[image: Normal]

**C is GONE LTR**

[image]

**C is GONE RTL**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this behavior is already fixed if you update to the current 1.1.0-beta5 of ConstraintLayout.